# conda update -n base -c defaults conda won't update to 4.6.x

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Hopefully the title says most of it. When I use conda, it informs me that there's a newer version; however, when I go to install conda, it refuses to install anything beyond 4.5.11. This problem is occurring on my laptop (running OS X Mojave). The Ubuntu virtual machine I'm running does not have this problem. It's been 9 days and no one has replied to my [conda Github issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8269), so I was hoping that someone here might be able to help out. That link contains relevant configuration details that may offer some clues.

```
$ conda update -n base -c defaults conda
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.5.11
  latest version: 4.6.4

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c defaults conda



# All requested packages already installed.
```

Comment: Can you check /Users/aberk/anaconda/conda-meta/pinned. Normally the file won't exist, but if you pinned conda to 4.5.11 in the past you'll see it in that file. If this is the case just remove the conda entry in that list.

Comment: This file does not exist, so I presume this is not the issue. Do you think it could be something else?

Comment: You can try including -v option (up to three time to increase verbose output) and see if it contains any clues

Comment: Same problem here. It's a known issue, and none of the advice about channels, pinning, or specific packages ever helped. Simply can't update from conda 4.5.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar problem, except that conda was reporting that I needed to update from 4.6.x to 4.7.x and that I needed to update by running:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

None of the other answers (as of the time I'm typing this) did the job immediately:

- My system only has Python 3, so a 2/3 issue wasn't the problem.
- Checking on torch and torchvision, I found that they were not part of my Anaconda installation, so that was not the problem either.
- Just trying to update Python didn't resolve the issue, as attempts to update conda still did not do anything.

On something of a whim, I ran

```
conda update anaconda
```

That did a a lot of updates (far more than should be listed here), which I then followed with:

```
conda update python
```

Again, there were many updates done; looking through the list, it was in this step that the conda update actually got done. Nonetheless, I still ran:

```
conda update conda
```

A few more updates were done at this point and these turned out to be the last ones. However, for good measure I ran:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Answer (score 2):

To update conda to the most recent version you have to update python:

(base) self@home:~$ conda update python

This updates many packages including:

conda: 4.5.11-py35_0 --> 4.6.11-py36_0

Comment: I have the same issue. I tried: `conda update python`, it did not work. I got the same issue as the person asking the question (@bashfuloctopus)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try the command: `conda install conda=4.6.4`, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to a conflict with a PyTorch installation in `base`. I removed `torch` and `torchvision` from the `base` env and this fixed the dependency snag.

Comment: I have the same problem and i do not have pytorch installed in `base`.

Comment: Did you try all of the comments above? Could you have another dependency conflict in `base`?

Comment: yep, I did not find any clue. I saved my env and now I try to reinstall.

Comment: and now i have conda latest version! (4.6.11)

Answer (score 0):

Following the procedure outlined in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6591) did the job for me.

tldr:

```
conda update -n base conda -c anaconda
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Loop in conda update problem, and finally I typed `which python` and found python2.7.

Maybe it's python version problem, you just need to update the python to python3.